# Is taking address of dangling reference UB?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Does the Standard say anything about this being UB (or not) ?

```
int& get()
{
    int a = 1;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << (&get() == nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Any usage by the caller of the reference returned by `get()` gives undefined behaviour.    Including computing the address.

Comment: Yes, the C++ Standard says this is UB.

Comment: Answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618783/why-is-returning-address-of-local-variable-or-temporary-only-a-warning-and-not-a

Comment: Don't really agree with this duplicate link: the code here is undefined behaviour, but the "duplicate" , in an attempt to be general, is too vague: many of the current answers say the code is OK, and they only cover a fraction of what would be a complete answer to the question

Comment: Problem with the duplicated question is no resolution.   Some of the up-voted answers say it is undefined behaviour, other up-voted answers say it isn't.